# What is the class of null?

Tags: java, null

In java when we assign null to any object like this:

```
private Apple apple = null;
```

Is there any class in java related to this `null`?

Because in Apache common-lang jar they have defined null like this:

```
public static class Null implements Serializable {
            /**
             * Required for serialization support. Declare serialization compatibility with Commons Lang 1.0            *             * @see java.io.Serializable
             */
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 7092611880189329093L;

            /**
            * Restricted constructor - singleton.
             */
            Null() {
               super();
            }

           /**
             * <p>Ensure singleton.</p>
            * 
           * @return the singleton value
             */
            private Object readResolve() {
                return ObjectUtils.NULL;
            }
       }
```

Why they have made it like this?

or it is just a bit pattern?

Comment: Note that `null instanceof AnyType` is always `false`, whatever `AnyType` is. (`null instanceof Null`, where `Null` is Apache's class, is also `false`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In java `null` is not an object and therefore does not have a class.

It does have a type though - see [the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.7).

Apache has created a class called `Null` (not `null`). This is an entirely different thing. I'm guessing they created it so they could represent `null` with an actual object - which may make programming easier in some ways.

Answer (score 0):

In java null is a keyword, not a class or object.